# Why this is giving an error[E0001:invalid syntax (<string>)] in python 3

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I tried to create an else statement that will check if there is a tie in the TicTacToe board:

```
#Checking for a tie:
else:
    #The board's numbers:
    for i in range(1,10):
        #If all or the numbers are not on the board, and no one won or lose...
        if all(not(i in board):
            #...then there's a tie! 
            print("Tie!")
        #If no one loses or won, and there's no tie, then the game isn't over.
        else:
            pass
```

Python gave said that there's a problem with this line:

```
if all(not(i in board):
```

This is the error:

```
E0001:invalid syntax (<string>, line 156)
```

How to fix the line?

Comment: Count your parentheses!

Answer (score 3):

Change`if all(not(i in board):` to `if all(not(i in board)):`.